# Facebook app request not getting displayed despite the increase of count

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, apprequests

I am using new javascript SDK to send app request to friends using app request dialog box. The code that I have used is as follows:-

```
    FB.ui({
        method : 'apprequests',
        display : 'iframe',
        to : '',
        data : '',
        title : 'Invite your friends to use Connect.',
        message : 'Hi, I am a friend of this site and I think you should join me! Register now to join our friendly group.',
        max_recipients : '5',
        },
        function(response) {
        if (response) {
            alert('Post was published.');                
        } 
        else
        {
            alert('Post was not published.');
        }
    });
```

Now, if I post a request using this code, the count displayed beside the "Apps and Ganmes" does get increased but when I click on "Apps and Games" to see the request sent from my site, it doesn't get displayed in the list. Moreover, in the sdk of this feature, it was mentioned that sending an app request through this code will also result in a notification but that too doesn't work.

This code, however, used to work when oauth2 was not activated. So, if anyone has the solution to this issue, please let me know as I need to fix it as early as possible.